# Issue with setting the text of a TextField with string from NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

**Description**

I am sure I am completely wrong in my line of thinking here, but do correct me. I am simply trying to reference a string I saved in one of my object subclasses. I am doing this by simply trying to set the text of a textField to the string i saved ( on a button click ).

**Code**

*Below you will find the code for my "CrawlerOne+CoreDataProperties.swift" file*

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension CrawlerOne {

@nonobjc class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CrawlerOne> {
    return NSFetchRequest<CrawlerOne>(entityName: "CrawlerOne");
}

@NSManaged var crawlerAbrasion: String?
@NSManaged var crawlerDistance: String?

}
```

*Here is the part that i am truly just guessing. This code is the "generate" button that is attempting to set the textField to be the string saved*

```
@IBAction func generate(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let entity1 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName:"CrawlerOne", into:context) as NSManagedObject as! CrawlerOne
    answer.text = entity1.crawlerAbrasion
}
```

*Finally, here is the code from where I initially saved the String. Note that these two functions are in difference classes & files*

```
@IBAction func save(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let entity1 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "CrawlerOne", into:context) as NSManagedObject as! CrawlerOne
    entity1.crawlerDistance = distance.text

}
```

**Conclusion**

Again, i am absolutely sure that my line of thinking here is just very off, but this is something that i am being pressured to complete very quickly. Also, there is absolutely no errors/messages in regards to this in the Debug Console. I simply click the button to add text to this Textfield and nothing happens. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: I am not sure why you try to downcast CrawlerOne to a managed object... have you tried just to cast it to CrawlerOne? Is there a subclass of NSManagedObject called CrawlerOne which you haven't listed here?

Comment: Could you explain your question to me? I am not very good with swift and am not sure what you mean. @ff10

Comment: See my edit: Is there a subclass of NSManagedObject called CrawlerOne which you haven't listed here?

Comment: Yes, CrawlerOne has a subclass. @ff10

Comment: Let me rephrase that: is there any code that looks like: `class CrawlerOne: NSManagedObject`?

Comment: Yes, it generated two files. The second one, not listed, is exactly what you typed. Sorry for not including it @ff10

Comment: Okay. In your function save can you try removing the `as NSManagedObject` and just leave `as! CrawlerOne`?

Comment: Sure, let me load and test that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120260/discussion-between-ff10-and-gavsta707).

Comment: I am, unfortunately, still not getting any results when i try to retrieve, even with the addition. @ff10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

- the property holding the String isn't identical in the generate and save methods
- not sure if you need to cast to NSManagedObject if CrawlerOne is already an NSManagedObject
- You are trying to fetch the String by inserting a new object in the managed context, using the result of that operation and therefore setting the label to a text that is nil. You need to create an NSFetchRequest with proper NSPredicates to fetch the original object from your NSManagedContext. You actually have one defined already in your CrawlerOne extension:

`class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CrawlerOne>`

Now you need to configure it to get the string(s) you are looking for. As mentioned, use `NSPredicate` for that. There's lots of examples of how to do that, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438587/fetch-object-by-property-in-core-data#1438696).